# synchronizing current database entries with new data to insert

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have to sync the data in my database table with new data from an sql query, where I need to delete the current entries which is not in the new data and insert the new entries which is not in the current data. I was able to do this in java using this pseudo code:

```
// 1) get all data in database and store it in list (currentList)
// 2) get new data obtained through sql query and store it in list (newList)
// 3) sync both list

for(entry : currentList) {
    if(newList.contains(entry))
        finalList.add(entry) 
}

for(entry : newList) {
    if(!finalList.contains(entry))
        finalList.add(entry)
}

// 4) delete all data from DB
// 5) insert finalList data to DB
```

It works fine, however, I think it will have performance issue when dealing with large set of data because I'm deleting everything and reinserting the whole list instead of just inserting the new entries and deleting the entries not found in the new data.

Can you suggest a better way of doing this? Is it possible to create an sql query that can take care of synchronizing of data?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606).

The construct will allow you to specify conditions under which to either update existing records, or to add new ones.

It basically looks like:

```
MERGE 
   INTO target_table
   USING source_table
 ON (some condition)
WHEN MATCHED 
     ( UPDATE some_update_statement )
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
     ( INSERT some_insert_statement )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do these operations in the stored procedure to not to unnecessarily increase DB traffic.

However this won't work for huge amount of entries (say millions of entries) or if each entry is a very big one. In this case try to use MERGE operations as Ryan pointed above.

Consider the following PL/SQL pseudocode (you may want to change it depending on your use case):

```
PROCEDURE replace_with_list (newList) AS
BEGIN
  /* Delete all the entries that are not present in the newList (e.g. by ID) */
  /* Insert all the entries that present in newList and not present in your table  */
END;
```